# How many cars can pass in hour at one certain point?

Tags: kinematics

I'am trying to calculate the number of cars wich can pass in a certain point in one hour. For example,
let's say this point it's 1 meter long, and cars are 2 meters long, cars are going 50km/hour, and space between cars is 3 meters. How much cars can pass in one hour?
[image]

Comment: Hi Ángel langdon. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: Hi, this is not a homework-like question, Is a question of pure physics, I want to know how to calculate the maximum number of cars which can pass in x seconds. It's a bit confusing for me to calculate that. But It is not for homework.